# ZPL: Binary B64 and compressed Z64 encoding

Tags: c#, zpl, zpl-ii

Maybe someone can help me with my Zebra ZPL problem. The ZPL manual doesn't really help me. 
I want to transfer binary (with ZPL B64) and compressed binary (with ZPL Z64) image data to the printer.

I was able to find the following information:

- with B64 the data is encoded in Base64 format.
- with Z64 the data is first compressed with LZ77 and then encoded with Base64.
- A CRC digit is appended to both encodings. (must probably be CRC-16) But I don't get a valid CRC check digit calculated!

Has any of you done that yet?

- With which parameters is the LZ77 algorithm used?
- Which CRC is used and with which start polynomial?
- Maybe someone even has a C# code for this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The ZPL manual doesn't really help me.

Tell me about it!

- The "LZ77" algorithm mentioned in the manual is in fact the ZLIB format. I used http://zlib.net for that.
- The "CRC" mentioned in the manual is in fact CRC16-CCITT. Code I used: http://sanity-free.com/133/crc_16_ccitt_in_csharp.html.

  In order to properly calculate it:

  - Compress the picture bits using ZLIB (the picture must be `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed`, and the picture bits are best accessed with [`Bitmap.LockBits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8)).
  - Encode the compressed data into Base64. **No whitespace or line breaks allowed.**
  - Convert the Base64 string to a byte array according to ASCII encoding (`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64string)`).
  - Calculate the CRC over that byte array. **The Initial CRC Value must be zero.**

Comment: While this helps, it would be nice to see a code example of this using current C# .NET commands.  An example of taking either a file or in memory bitmap and compressing it, encoding it, calculating the CRC, and what the final ZPL would look like using the ~DY command would help me.  I've tried to figure it out from this comment but can't get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

These two pages contain interesting code in Java to write a converter encoding an image file to Z64 :

http://www.jcgonzalez.com/img-to-zpl-online

https://gist.github.com/trevarj/1255e5cbc08fb3f79c3f255e25989a18

I wrote a Python port of the Java class of the first link, taking the form of a Python3 class :
https://github.com/ftheeten/python_zebra_adapter/blob/main/class_zebra.py

You can use afterwards the Python Pillow library to generate the images to be converted. This approach is very flexible as you can use any font having a TTF file.

E.G.

```
import socket
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import numpy as np
...

img=FUNCTION_GENERATING_A_PILLOW
zpl=Class_zpl()
zpl.set_compress(False)
zpl.set_blacklight_percentage(60)
str_label=zpl.process(img)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((PRINTER_IP, PORT_PRINTER))
s.sendall(str.encode(str_label))
#data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```